# How to fix "ReferenceError: window is not defined" error in angular 6 universal server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular6, angular-universal

I execute the following command on angular cli command line tool,
to install universal package for angular6
'ng add @ng-toolkit/universal'.
It installed good,after that i execute npm run build:prod and it also runs very well.
Now finally I run 'npm run server'.But this throws me error without giving me launching url.

here it is throwing error in server.js file , how to fix it.

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.exports.__esModule (D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122614:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122314:31)
    at Object.exports.__esModule (D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122359:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122314:31)
    at Object.exports.__esModule (D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122343:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122314:31)
    at D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122334:19
    at D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122337:11
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122292:21)
    at Object.exports.__esModule (D:\ANGULAR2\dist\server.js:122294:4)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rssmtechwood@0.0.0 serverrl `node local.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

as a workaround i replace window with global.

var work = global.document.createElement('div');
but window,document element is being used in many places of server.js

```
function(module, exports)

{   

        'use strict';   

        exports.__esModule = true;

        var tagSoup = false;

        var selfClose = false;  

        var work = window.document.createElement('div');

}


function isBrowser() 

{

    return (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.document !== 'undefined');

}
```

I expect window.document,window to be replaced by nodejs syntax for the above sample code.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: simply saying , browser related keywords like window,document are giving as error when i try to execute 'npm run server' in angular cli command tool.

Answer (score 3):

When running your app on Angular Universal, the `document`, `window` and `navigator` objects will always be `undefined` and have no equivalent.

The reason is simple, when running an Angular app on client side, an (almost) empty HTML file is served, then the JavaScript takes over, and modifies the DOM by using `window`, `document`, etc.

When running an Angular app on server side, the execution context is totally different, Node.js has no knowledge of any browser, it just generates HTML as a full plain string without interpreting it at all. That's why those keywords can't be used in this context.

So whatever you are trying to achieve with those keywords, you'll have to find a different way for server-side rendering, or just conditionally disable this code, so it only executes on client side, and doesn't throw errors on server side.

Comment: Actually i followed this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxG9nuvnh-A
and done step by step execution of launching my url.
step 1:he executes ng add @ng-toolkit/universal
Note:ng add @ng-toolkit/universal produces server.js  file automatically in dist folder.
step 2:executes npm run build:prod
step 3:Finally he executes npm run server.

Comment: c:\users\gary\code\awesome-seo>npm run server
so his output is like this,
>awesome-seo@0.0.0 server c:\users\gary\code\awesome-seo
>node local.js
Listening on :http://localhost:8080
That's all, he can view the page in the above url, it does not throw any errors.
So what is the mistake I have done, please spot it?

Comment: I cannot give you informations about third party tools like the one you are using. I'm just explaining the root cause of the problem you're experiencing to help you understand what's wrong in the boilerplate generated by this tool.